# Can we redirect from Console application to a web application in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I just need redirect from console to web url, Is that possible in dot net C#?
my code is below.

```
 public static class Program
    {
       public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
         Console.Write("Waiting for a connect to http://www.abcde.com");
         Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

is that possible in C#?
Please suggest.

Comment: you want to open an internet explorer with the desired URL?

Answer (score 10):

To open a url in the default browser, you can use

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to open the website with the default installed webbrowser you can use

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Answer (score 6):

As stated in the other answers you can open a web page with 
`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://stackoverflow.com");` - this opens the page in the computers default browser.

If you want to specify which program to open it with you can use something like this;

```
    // open in Internet Explorer
    Process.Start("iexplore", "http://stackoverflow.com/");
```